# elasticsearch bool query combine must with OR

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently trying to migrate a solr-based application to elasticsearch.

I have this lucene query:

```
(( 
    name:(+foo +bar) 
    OR info:(+foo +bar) 
)) AND state:(1) AND (has_image:(0) OR has_image:(1)^100)
```

As far as I understand this is a combination of `must` clauses combined with boolean `OR`:

> Get all documents containing `(foo AND bar in name) OR (foo AND bar in info)`. After that filter results by condition `state=1` and boost documents that have an image.

I have been trying to use a bool query with `must` but I am failing to get boolean `OR` into `must` clauses. Here is what I have:

```
GET /test/object/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "foo"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "bar"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "has_image": {
              "query": 1,
              "boost": 100
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, `must` conditions for `info` are missing.

** UPDATE **

I have updated my elasticsearch query and got rid of that function score. My base problem still exists.

Comment: There is a good documentation on combining ElasticSearch queries here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html

Comment: As of v7.10, here's the new documentation on boolean queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html  I do believe that documentation could be improved with examples to make it much more clear about simple cases like this OR question...

Comment: The explanation in [Elasticsearch - The Definitive Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html) is much better than [the current doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). Although it states it's for 2.x but most still applies. Thanks for sharing the links!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I finally managed to create a query that does exactly what i wanted to have:

A filtered nested boolean query.
I am not sure why this is not documented. Maybe someone here can tell me?

Here is the query:

```
GET /test/object/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "sort": {
    "_score": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "state": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "name": "foo"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "name": "bar"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "has_image": {
                        "query": 1,
                        "boost": 100
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "info": "foo"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "info": "bar"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "has_image": {
                        "query": 1,
                        "boost": 100
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

In pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM /test/object
WHERE 
    ((name=foo AND name=bar) OR (info=foo AND info=bar))
AND state=1
```

Please keep in mind that it depends on your document field analysis and mappings how name=foo is internally handled. This can vary from a fuzzy to strict behavior.

"minimum_should_match": 1 says, that at least one of the should statements must be true.

This statements means that whenever there is a document in the resultset that contains has_image:1 it is boosted by factor 100. This changes result ordering.

```
"should": [
  {
    "match": {
      "has_image": {
        "query": 1,
        "boost": 100
      }
    }
   }
 ]
```

Have fun guys :)

Comment: Holy crap. Does anyone have a better solution? Thanks for posting this, but that is absolutely way too much complexity to achieve a Logical OR in a query.

Comment: Not only is this query unneccesarily long, its using deprecated syntax. @daniel-fackrell answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: @EricAlford This answer from 2015 is based on a earlier version of ES. Feel free to provide a better solution.

Comment: Idea: Take over / fork ElasticSearch, rewrite it in a user-friendly way, add simple query language to it, WIN! We just need funding. I'm in! Who else ?

Comment: @Sliq what about this - https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-sql

Comment: Pseudo-SQL looks like incorrect: `(name=foo AND name=bar)` alvays is `False`, and `(info=foo AND info=bar)` also. So WHERE condition always would be `False`

Answer (score 825):

- **OR** is spelled **should**
- **AND** is spelled **must**
- **NOR** is spelled **must_not**

Example:

You want to see all the items that are (round AND (red OR blue)):

```json
    {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "term": {"shape": "round"}
                    },
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"term": {"color": "red"}},
                                {"term": {"color": "blue"}}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also do more complex versions of OR, for example, if you want to match at least 3 out of 5, you can specify 5 options under "should" and set a "minimum_should" of 3.

Thanks to Glen Thompson and Sebastialonso for finding where my nesting wasn't quite right before.

Thanks also to Fatmajk for pointing out that "term" becomes a "match" in ElasticSearch Version 6.

Comment: Would pulling the `should` into the upper-level `bool`, and including a `minimum_should_match: 1` work?

Comment: @Sid It would not.

In that case, we would only require {"shape": "round"}, and the "should" would apply ordering to the results that had a shape of round, because at that level it's optional. We can only make it required by nesting under the "must".

Comment: When I try this example I get back `[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]`. Is this somehow version dependent?

Comment: @DanneJ Apparently, you need to include the "shape":"round" element in a single object, and the inner "bool" part in a sibling object. That works, but it seems it's not the same query.

Answer (score 63):

This is how you can nest multiple bool queries in one outer bool query
this using Kibana,

- **bool** indicates we are using boolean
- **must** is for **AND**
- **should** is for **OR**

```
GET my_inedx/my_type/_search
{
  "query" : {
     "bool": {             //bool indicates we are using boolean operator
          "must" : [       //must is for **AND**
               {
                 "match" : {
                       "description" : "some text"  
                   }
               },
               {
                  "match" :{
                        "type" : "some Type"
                   }
               },
               {
                  "bool" : {          //here its a nested boolean query
                        "should" : [  //should is for **OR**
                               {
                                 "match" : {
                                     //ur query
                                }
                               },
                               { 
                                  "match" : {} 
                               }     
                             ]
                        }
               }
           ]
      }
  }
}
```

This is how you can nest a query in ES

---

There are more types in "bool" like,

1. Filter
2. must_not

Answer (score 10):

I recently had to solve this problem too, and after a LOT of trial and error I came up with this (in PHP, but maps directly to the DSL):

```
'query' => [
    'bool' => [
        'should' => [
            ['prefix' => ['name_first' => $query]],
            ['prefix' => ['name_last' => $query]],
            ['prefix' => ['phone' => $query]],
            ['prefix' => ['email' => $query]],
            [
                'multi_match' => [
                    'query' => $query,
                    'type' => 'cross_fields',
                    'operator' => 'and',
                    'fields' => ['name_first', 'name_last']
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'minimum_should_match' => 1,
        'filter' => [
            ['term' => ['state' => 'active']],
            ['term' => ['company_id' => $companyId]]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Which maps to something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT * from <index> 
WHERE (
    name_first LIKE '<query>%' OR
    name_last LIKE '<query>%' OR
    phone LIKE  '<query>%' OR
    email LIKE '<query>%'
)
AND state = 'active'
AND company_id = <query>
```

The key in all this is the `minimum_should_match` setting. Without this the `filter` totally overrides the `should`.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: This appears to be a better answer than the currently accepted answer

Comment: how we can implement  `LIKE '%<query>%'` ?

Answer (score 7):

If you were using Solr's default or Lucene query parser, you can pretty much always put it into a [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(( name:(+foo +bar) OR info:(+foo +bar)  )) AND state:(1) AND (has_image:(0) OR has_image:(1)^100)"
    }
  }
}
```

That said, you may want to use a [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), like the one you already posted, or even a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filterQuery = $this->queryFactory->create(QueryInterface::TYPE_BOOL, ['must' => $queries,'should'=>$queriesGeo]);
```

In `must` you need to add the query condition array which you want to work with `AND` and in `should` you need to add the query condition which you want to work with `OR`.

You can check this: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/972