# What is "state" used for in filtered queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

I had a question which corresponds to an [existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or) (about the possibility to combine several layers of booleans).

There is a comment in the answer which I do not understand:

> A filtered nested boolean query. I am not sure why this is not
>   documented.

While I managed, based on the answer, to construct a query similar to `((a<10 AND b=="hello") OR (a<3 AND b=="world"))` (to quote a comment to the answer "Holy crap."), I do not understand the first part of the answer query, namely

```
"filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "state": 1
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

**What is it for? Is it useful?**

Comment: :-) the poster wrote this query that had issues with: `(( 
    name:(+foo +bar) 
    OR info:(+foo +bar) 
)) AND state:(1) AND (has_image:(0) OR has_image:(1)^100)`. As you can see there is a `state` in there. Most likely that is a another field this poster has in his/her documents.

Comment: That absolutely was my intention. It is just a boolean field in my document I wanted to set a filter on. Next time you should probably just ask below my ticket, so I am informed and can answer you more quickly.