# Elasticsearch bool query must match single field single term, and another field with OR terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to find a document with a **name** that contains 'Bob' and has a **location** that is in either 'paducah' or 'smyrna'.

Here's what I have now:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    must: [
      { match: { name: 'bob' } }, 
      { match: { location: ['paducah', 'smyrna'] } }
    ],
  },
},
```

I know the problem is in the **location** array, because if i change it to a single element with no array the query works just fine.

[This is the closest answer i could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or).

It didn't work, i receive the following error:

> [term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this query:

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          { "match": { "name": "bob" } }
        ],
        "should": [
            { "match": { "location": "paducah" }},
            { "match": { "location": "smyrna"   }}
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "name": "bob" }, 
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {"term": {"location": "paducah"}},
            {"term": {"location": "smyrna"}}
          ]
        }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```