# Convert MySQL query (with where condition) to Elasticsearch query

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I need to "transform" mysql query to Elasticsearch query. What is blocking me is "where" statement. Basically what I need is to find all items that are within distance of 25 miles based on latitude and longitude and where pickup is enabled **OR** where items do have delivery enabled and provided zip code

```
where
(
    (
        `enabled_pickup` = '1'
        and(
            ST_Distance_Sphere(
                POINT(- 122.41941550000001 , 37.7749295) ,
                geolocation
            ) / 1000 * 0.62137119223733
        ) <= 25
    )
    or(
        `enabled_delivery` = '1'
        `zip_code` = '94116'
    )
)
```

and this is Elasticsearch query that is not working as expected

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "enabled_pickup": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "25 mi",
                    "geo_location": {
                      "lat": "37.7749295",
                      "lon": "-122.41941550000001"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "dispensary.delivery": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "zip_code": "94116"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}
}

can somebody please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading about the similar issue, you can give a try with below query. you can find a similar question being solved by [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or)

Hope this helps, Cheers!

```
{
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                            {"match": { "enabled_pickup": "1"}}
                            ,{ "match": {
                                  "geo_distance": { 
                                        "distance": "25 mi", 
                                        "geo_location": {
                                            "lat": "37.7749295",
                                            "lon": "-122.41941550000001"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                  ,
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                            { "match": {"dispensary.delivery": "1"} }
                            ,{"match": {"zip_code": "94116"} }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```