# Elasticsearch tutorial OR search (combining must and should)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

to get started with elasticsearch and kibana I tried the tutorial. But now I get an error I can't solve on my own.

It's pretty smiliar to this one: [elasticsearch bool query combine must with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or)

But the solution from Daniel Fackrell doesn't work for me, I am clearly missing something. My Code:

```
POST shakespeare/scene/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "play_name": "Antony"
          },
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "speaker": "Demetrius"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "speaker": "Antony"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But then I get the following error: "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]"

After searching and looking around for a few hours I hope someone can help me.

I'm using version 5.6.4.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards
Greg

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a bracket. Check the query below.

```
POST shakespeare/scene/_search/
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "play_name": "Antony"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "speaker": "Demetrius"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "speaker": "Antony"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Silly me. Thank you very much!