# How to nest bool queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a search query which dynamically adds a set of constraints (`bool`) to the query. The general expected structure is as follows

```
OR (

AND (
    condition
    condition
    ...
)

AND (
    condition
    condition
    ...
)

)
```

In other words I have a set (one or more) of conditions which must all be met (`AND` above). There may be several of such sets, any of them should be enough for the final match (the `OR` above).

An example of such structure, as generated by my code (this is the full API query, the generated part is `"bool"`):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "attack_ip": "10.89.7.117"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "sentinel_port": "17"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "attack_ip": "10.89.7.118"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "range": {
      "eventtime": {
        "gte": "2018-03-05T12:47:22.397+01:00"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "src": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attack_ip",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dst": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sentinel_hostname_lan",
            "size": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My understanding of this query was:

- if `"attack_ip === 10.89.7.117"` and `"sentinel_port === 17"`
- or
- if `"attack_ip === 10.89.7.118"`

the entry will match

Unfortunately I get upon calling Elasticsearch the error

```
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 177
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 1,
    "col": 177
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

What does this error mean?

#### EDIT

Following Piotr's answer, I tried to move the `range` constraint into the boolean part. I get the same error, though.

My query is [available online for easier reading](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=ae47348645bc20828df7392217640cd5) and reproduced below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "attack_ip": "10.89.7.117"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "sentinel_port": "17"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "attack_ip": "10.89.7.118"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "eventtime": {
              "gte": "2018-03-05T13:55:27.927+01:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
      "src": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "attack_ip",
          "size": 1000
        },
        "aggs": {
          "dst": {
            "terms": {
              "field": "sentinel_hostname_lan",
              "size": 2000
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40755927/4614788

Comment: @GlennVanSchil: This is a good question about how ot use the bool in general - I directly used the documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html. I do not see how it solves my current problem, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you have is with `range` part. Try to move it inside the `bool`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [{
          "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                  "attack_ip": "10.89.7.117"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "sentinel_port": "17"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "attack_ip": "10.89.7.118"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": {
        "range": {
          "eventtime": {
            "gte": "2018-03-05T12:47:22.397+01:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "src": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attack_ip",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dst": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sentinel_hostname_lan",
            "size": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or move it to `filter` section:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [{
          "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "term": {
                  "attack_ip": "10.89.7.117"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "sentinel_port": "17"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "attack_ip": "10.89.7.118"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
            "range": {
              "eventtime": {
                "gte": "2018-03-05T12:47:22.397+01:00"
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "src": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "attack_ip",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "dst": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sentinel_hostname_lan",
            "size": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope I formatted this correctly. Please let me know if you have any issues.

In the end, it is possible that you will need to specify [`minimum_should_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) param for [`bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to get correct results.

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that the range should be part of the boolean section. I updated my question with the query (and a link to an online viewer which makes life easier) but I still have  the same issue

Comment: I am analyzing your query and I do not understand one thing: why didn't you put two must conditions (the range and the set of ORs (should)) . that would translate to "the date must be in the range AND one or more of the blocks of terms must be matched")

Comment: You missed one thing in my code - you have to have "size" and "aggs" at the same level as "query", not inside "query". Take a look at: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=7923d877cf3c1dfc07eaf943715ed9a1

Comment: BTW. When you have "size" == 0 you will get zero results.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I completely missed the fact that I included the aggregation in the query. Now it works correctly. Thanks again. As for the size: 0, I am not interested in individual hits but  only in the aggregations.