# ElasticSearch multiple terms search json

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a ton of items in a Db with many columns. I need to search across two of these columns to get one data set. 
The first column, `genericCode`, would group together any of the rows that have that code. 
The second column, `genericId`, is calling out a specific row to add because it is missing the list of `genericCode`'s i'm looking for.

The back-end C# sets up my json for me as follows, but it returns nothing.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "aggs": {
    "paramA": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "paramA"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "paramA.name",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "specValues": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "paramA.value",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "locationId": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "genericCode": [
              "10A",
              "20B"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "genericId": [
              11223344
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get and empty result set. If I remove either of the `"terms"` I get what I would expect. So, I just need to combine those terms into one search.

I've gone through a lot of the documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html 
and still can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Let's say I'm Jelly Belly and I want to create a bag of jelly beans with all the Star Wars and Disney jelly beans, and I also want to add all beans of the color green. That is basically what I'm trying to do.

EDIT: Changing the `"must"` to '"should"` isn't quite right either. I need it to be (in pseudo sql):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
Where locationId = 1
AND (
  genericCode = "this", "that
  OR
  genericId = 1234, 5678
  )
```

The `locationId` separates our data in an important way.

I found this post: [elasticsearch bool query combine must with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or#40755927)
and it has gotten me closer, but not all the way there...

I've tried several iterations of should > must > should > must building this query and get varying results, but nothing accurate.

Comment: I believe You should use "should" instead of "must". must = AND. should = OR

Comment: @rAndom69 Nailed it! *smh* I should have realized that sooner

Comment: @rAndom69 ... damn, not quite nailed it... See edit above.

Comment: bool queries can be nested (according to documentation), tho I don't think I ever used it. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html.

Comment: you need a nested bool/should for last two conditions

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that is working. It helped when I realized I was passing in the wrong data for one of my parameters. *doh*

Nest the `should` inside the `must` as @khachik noted in the comment above. I had this some time ago but it wasn't working due to the above blunder.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "aggs": {
    "specs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "paramA"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "paramA.name",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "specValues": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "paramA.value",
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "locationId": {
              "value": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "genericCode": [
                    "101",
                    "102"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "genericId": [
                    3078711,
                    3119430
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```