# Combining `term` and `match` in `should`

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to search items that either have `firstField` (mapped as text) similar to a query string or `secondField` (mapped as an integer) equal to 1.

After reading [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/), I understand I should be using `bool` with `should` (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or#answer-40755927)):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {"match": {"firstField":  "queryString"}},
        {"term":  {"secondField": 1}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The results however show that `secondField` contributes far less to the result than `firstField` does since their scoring algorithms produce different scales.

I am considering artifically `boost`ing the `secondField` (though I am guessing this would only work in some cases) or normalizing `firstField` to somehow represent a percentage instead of an arbitrary score.

Is there a proper way to give each field the same weight?

Note: I am using `ES 7.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't want scoring to happen. I such case use [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "firstField": "queryString"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "secondField": 1
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I do want scoring to happen. I'd like the fields to be scored according to the same scale (e.g. 0 to 1, 1 being a perfect `match` or positive `term`, 0 being totally irrelevant) so that I can give precedence to one compared to the other.