# I have written mysql query wanted to convert same in elastic search query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

'''select count(*) as count from activity where project_id in (61,129) and (entry_device_id in (1068,1069) or exit_device_id in (1068,1069) );'''

I tried with should in elastic query and match but not getting the desired results.

Got some idea from [elasticsearch bool query combine must with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or)

And tried but not getting the correct results.

Need help in this

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your index's mapping, a combination of [`terms` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) should get you started:

```json
GET your_activity_index/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "project_id": [ 61, 129 ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "entry_device_id": [ 1068, 1069 ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "exit_device_id": [ 1068, 1069 ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```