# How to put or condition in two different keys in DSL query

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have dsl query which need to return

- Country Owner is list of dictionaries
- Territory Owner is list of dictionaries
- Need to check where id is part of that dictionary
- My query which is below which return which is `'and'` but i need `OR` operation

```
a = {'from': 0, 'size': 200,'query': {
    'bool': {
      'must': [
        {
          'terms': {
            'Country Owner.id.keyword': [
              'ABC101'
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          'terms': {
            'Territory Owner.id.keyword': [
              'ABC101'
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40755927/13210997 this could be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `must` by `should` and you're good to go

```
a = {'from': 0, 'size': 200,'query': {
    'bool': {
      'minimum_should_match': 1,                <--- change this
      'should': [                               <--- change this
        {
          'terms': {
            'Country Owner.id.keyword': [
              'ABC101'
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          'terms': {
            'Territory Owner.id.keyword': [
              'ABC101'
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why minimum_should_match, is that required?

Comment: It's only necessary if you're going to add filter or must clauses along the way, but if you have only should, you can ditch it... even though it doesn't hurt leaving it