# How do I combine elasticsearch filter queries with OR using the Java API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have these fields:

- country (can be "DK", "US", "UK" and so on)
- media ("book", "ebook", "cd")
- state ("active", "inactive")

I would like to search for all documents that have **country="DK" AND ((media="book" AND state="inactive") OR (media="ebook" AND state="ACTIVE)**

I am creating a **BoolQueryBuilder** like this:

```
        BoolQueryBuilder bqb = QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("country", "DK"));
        bqb.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("media", "book"));
        bqb.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("state", "inactive");

        NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(bqb)
                .build();
```

From what I can understand from this Stackoverflow question: [elasticsearch bool query combine must with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or) I should create a query looking like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {"country": "DK"}
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {"term": {"media": "book"}},
                                        {"term": {"state": "inactive"}}
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [
                                        {"term": {"media": "ebook"}},
                                        {"term": {"state": "active"}}
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is this correct?
How do I do this with the Java API?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error this seems to work:

```
        BoolQueryBuilder bqb = QueryBuilders
                .boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("country", "DK"));

        BoolQueryBuilder query1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        query1.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("media", "book"));
        query1.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("state", "inactive");

        BoolQueryBuilder query2 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
        query2.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("media", "ebook"));
        query2.filter(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("state", "active");

        bqb.filter(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(query1).should(query2));

        NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(bqb)
                .build();
```

And it generated this query:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "country" : [
            "DK"
          ],
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : [
            {
              "bool" : {
                "filter" : [
                  {
                    "terms" : {
                      "media" : [
                        "book"
                      ],
                      "boost" : 1.0
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms" : {
                      "state" : [
                        "inactive"
                      ],
                      "boost" : 1.0
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            },
            {
              "bool" : {
                "filter" : [
                  {
                    "terms" : {
                      "media" : [
                        "ebook"
                      ],
                      "boost" : 1.0
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms" : {
                      "state" : [
                        "active"
                      ],
                      "boost" : 1.0
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice find. I'm using the new query builder for Spring Boot 3+ and you now have to use the fluent syntax...

`QueryBuilders.bool(b -> b.should(q1).should(q2));`