# How do i combine different search parameters in an elasticscearch dsl query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Good day together,

I have a little problem in Elastic/Kibana. In the Kibana Query Language "KQL" it is possible for me to execute a certain query:

```
car:* AND coun: * AND doc: (bes* OR *rvr*) AND NOT coun: (SIP OR LUK)
```

I would like to use this as a filter query using Elasticscearch query DSL. Only I don't get the same result. For this I use the boolean operator. My query looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "car"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "coun"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "doc.keyword": {
              "value": "bes*"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "doc.keyword": {
              "value": "*rvr*"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "coun.keyword": "SIP"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "coun.keyword": "LUK"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I do not get the same result. My guess is the "should" operator. But I don't know exactly how to adjust the code.

I would be very grateful for any answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elasticsearch bool query combine must with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here, that you putting OR outside AND. Just move `should` clause inside `must`. Like this

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "car"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "con"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "doc.keyword": {
                    "value": "bes*"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "doc.keyword": {
                    "value": "*rvr*"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "coun.keyword": "SIP"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "coun.keyword": "LUK"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```