# ElasticSearch exclude with if condition

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-plugin, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to write a query that gives me results with the following condition:

get all user data with multiple statues but on certain status, only get it if another filed equals some value.

user data has the following statuses: "processing", "pending", "accepted", "rejected"

get them all but on "processing" status, get data if some field equals some value.

appreciated your help

i expect to get all user data but data that has "processing" status unless some another field equals some value

Comment: Could you please provide some documents as example ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elasticsearch bool query combine must with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or)