# Elasticsearch, is it possible to query an index with two different type that have different set of fields?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have an index with two different types :

```
    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 408863
            [max_score] => 1
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => myindex
                            [_type] => merch
                            [_id] => 379919
                            [_score] => 1
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 379919
                                    [field1] =>  Lorem ipsum
                                    [field2] => ERKDK56
                                    [field3] => 1256
...


    [hits] => Array
        (
            [total] => 4172386
            [max_score] => 1
            [hits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [_index] => myindex
                            [_type] => merchSeller
                            [_id] => 2599218
                            [_score] => 1
                            [_source] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2599218
                                    [field4] => 1
                                    [field5] => 1
                                    [merch] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 132539
                                            [field6] => 132539
                                        )
                                    [seller] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 689
                                            [field7] => 1
...
```

**How can I create a query that can check the fields of both types?**

I created a query by adding both type in the type field hoping I wil have access to there fields but it does not return good result.

```
$params = [            
    'index' => 'myindex',
    'type' => 'merch,merchSeller',
    'body' => [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must'=> [
                'match' => ['field1' => 'Lorem'] ,
            ],
            'must'=> [
                'match' => ['field4' => '23'],
            ]
        ]
    ]]
];
```

I'm using laravel with "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~7.1".

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [elasticsearch bool query combine must with OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538760/elasticsearch-bool-query-combine-must-with-or)

Comment: Thanks but no. I'm looking for a way to get data from an index that has two type each with different fields.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting records with _type equals to merc and match on field1 or records with _type equals to merchSeller and match on field4

```
  "query": {
        "bool" :  {
          "should": [ 
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ {
                  "term":{"_type":"merch"}
                },
                {
                  "term":{"field1" : "Lorem ipsum"}
                }
                  ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ {
                  "term":{"_type":"merchSeller"}
                },
                {
                  "term":{"field4" : "23"}
                }
                  ]
              }
              
            }

          ]
        }
```

}

Be aware that _type is deprecated.